# R capture Postgres function notice

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm trying to capture a psql "raise" messagges from R but I don't seem able to achive such result and the RPostgreSQL manual does not seem to contain this piece of information...

I post some basic code which should illustrate my problem.

Postgres function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verbose() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
    raise info 'an info';

    return 0;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

R code (executes the psql function and retrives the result):

```
sql = "SELECT verbose();";
con = dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), user=user, password=password, dbname=dbname, host=host);
rs = dbGetQuery(con, sql);
dbDisconnect(con);
```

What I want is capturing the string "an info".
I've tried the following R code:

```
# test 1:
x = capture.output(dbGetQuery(con, sql));
x; 
# output:
# verbose
#       0

# test 2:
x = tryCatch(dbGetQuery(con, sql), error=function(err)cat("error\n",err), warning=function(w)cat("warning\n",w), messagge=function(msg)cat("messagge\n",msg));
x; 
# output:
# verbose
#       0
```

but it does not work... Any idea?

Comment: check the error stack. postgres raises to `STDERR` I believe

Comment: May I ask you to post an example?

Comment: no, sorry - I'm not `R` guy - I'm on the other side

Comment: hi @BrunoZamengo, i know this is old question, but did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: Sadly no... I moved to other DBMSs so I just gave up...